# how to get a Bundle Path in Swift 3

Tags: swift, swift3, path, nsbundle

I try to get a Bundle path in Swift 3 yet it always says 'unresolved identifier Bundle' whenever I use: `guard let Path = Bundle.main.path(ResolvedName: name , ofType : type)`.

Has Swift now changed the use Bundle?
or do I have to create some type of NSBundle Value like a variable before I can use these identifiers?

I have searched the Web and can't seem to find anything which solves the problem.

Here is my Code:

```
import Foundation

enum PlistError: ErrorType {
    case invalidResource
    case parsingFailure
}

class PlistLoader {
    static func array(fromFile name: String, ofType type: String) throws -> [[String: String]] {
        guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: name, ofType: type) else {
            throw PlistError.invalidResource
        }

        guard let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [[String: String]] else {
            throw PlistError.parsingFailure
        }

        return array
    }
}

class ContactsSource {
    static var contacts: [Contact] {
        let data = try! PlistLoader.array(fromFile: "ContactsDB", ofType: "plist")
        return data.flatMap { Contact(dictionary: $0) }
    }

}
```

Comment: Could this be one of those situations where you need to quit Xcode and clean out the DerivedData folder? Sometimes Xcode just needs this sort of nudge (or perhaps it's more a slap in the head).

Comment: The only error I see with your code is the use of `ErrorType`, which was renamed to `Error` in Swift 3. Other than that, it compiles with Swift 3.1 (well, once I define `Contact`, since you left it out)

Comment: when i used Error as i thought it should be using it said Unresolved Identifier Error , everything works in mine except Bundle

Comment: i may be using an older version of Swift or something , i thought i was up to Date , i'll see if i am using an outdated version and come back if i am using Swift 3

Comment: yeah , i was using Swift 2.1.1

Comment: You should delete this question. It won't help any future readers.